# error in while loop with editing and emailing of files and Thread.Sleep(1000)

Tags: c#

I'm getting the error 'IOException: The process cannot access the file file path because it is being used by another process' but i cant seem to grasp why. I was getting it in my bigger project but I didnt want this post to have a huge code block so i tried to shortern it down so please excuse the stupid class names and variable names.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading;

namespace Test_Bench
{
    public class poo
    {
        public void penises()
        {
            StreamWriter chinatown;
            chinatown = new     StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\eggroll\\Desktop\\file.txt");
            chinatown.Write("SUP BOIS");
            chinatown.Close();
        }
    }
    public class hello
    {
        public void eggroll()
        {
            MailAddress senderAddress = new MailAddress("example@gmail.com");

            MailAddress receiverAddress = new MailAddress("example@gmail.com");

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(senderAddress, receiverAddress);

            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
            attachment = new     System.Net.Mail.Attachment("C:\\Users\\example\\Desktop\\file.txt");
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;

            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                "example@gmail.com", "example");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var chicken = new poo();
            var hello = new hello();
            while (true)
            {
                chicken.penises();
                hello.eggroll();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you get this exception with your current posted code?

Comment: The names are indeed stupid. Can't you give their names a bit more meaning? It reads a bit like obfuscated code. Where did you get the `IOException`? Does it happen when you write the file or when you send the attachment?

Answer (score 1):

You need to dispose the `MailMessage` so that it closes all its connections and frees any resource handles that it might have open (for example, handles to attachments):

```
public class hello
{
    public void eggroll()
    {
        MailAddress senderAddress = new MailAddress("example@gmail.com");

        MailAddress receiverAddress = new MailAddress("example@gmail.com");

        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(senderAddress, receiverAddress))
        {
            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
            attachment = new     System.Net.Mail.Attachment("C:\\Users\\example\\Desktop\\file.txt");
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;

            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                "example@gmail.com", "example");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
    }
}
```

This is particularly important when you are sending mail attachments.